# the meaning of the verb "communicate"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> *Must*, *need* and *do*...*have to* are all used in a complaining type of question (usually with a second-person subject) already mentioned in §117Aa:

> Need you be so rude? | Do we have to have rice pudding every day? | Must you drop ash all over my carpet?

> Although the logical meaning of these verbs is ‘Is it obligatory / necessary...?’ **the force of the question is probably ironic, communicating at two levels**: ‘Is it a fact that you can’t help this annoying behaviour? (But, of course, I know very well that you could help it if you wanted to!)’

(from <Meaning and the Engnlish Verb 3rd ed.> by Geoffrey Leech)

1. Here, "the force of the question is probably ironic, communicating at two levels" is equal to the following?

"the force of the question is probably ironic and communicates at two levels"

2. Here, two levels mean the following?

first level: Is it a fact that you can’t help this annoying behaviour?

second level: Of course, I know very well that you could help it if you wanted to!

3. Then, what's the exact meaning(or dictionary definition) of the verb "communicate"?

Comment: To communicate is to express yourself. - talking, explaining, writing, emailing, texting. **Need you** says level 1 (can't stop it) and level 2 (don't want to stop it.) It communicates both meanings through the rich irony that English allows.

Comment: 1. Then, the communicating of Need you...? at level 1 is simply based on the logical meaning(i.e. necessary or obligatory) of the verb *need* and the communicating of Need you...? at level 2 is based on the ironical element which the speaker has captured from the verb *need*, so the answer to my second question is yes?

Comment: 2. Secondly, here the word *communicate* is equivalent to the word *convey*?

Comment: 3. lastly, the answer to my first question is also yes?

Comment: 1 yes. 2 yes. 3 yes.

Comment: Is this your third question? "what's the exact meaning(or dictionary definition) of the verb "communicate"?"

Comment: @JavaLatte Yes, it's my 3rd question.

Comment: @gonjuyi what don't you understand about a dictionary definition like the first one here? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/communicate It seems to fit perfectly in the sentence that you quoted

Comment: @JavaLatte 1. If "the force of the question is probably ironic, communicating at two levels" equals to "the force of the question is probably ironic and communicates at two levels", then the subject of the verb "communicate" will be "something(=the force of the question)". But, the first definition of your link seems to fit for someone as the subject, you know.

Comment: 2. If "the force of the question is probably ironic, communicating at two levels" equals to "the force of the question is probably ironic and communicates at two levels", then the verb "communicate" will be an intransitive verb. So I wondered the exact meaning of the intransitive verb "communicate" in quoted sentence.

Comment: As the dictionary says, communicate is about sharing information. The issue with your sentence is not the specific meaning of the sentence- that is clear- but with the unusual structure of the sentence. The person who is speaking is communicating, not the question itself or the force of the question.

Comment: @JavaLatte Yeah, that's the point. I agree that the sentence of "the force of the question is probably ironic, communicating at two levels" has the unusual structure. That is, if the first definition of your link is intended through the verb "communicate" by the author, the structure of the sentence is awkward.

Comment: @gonjuyi I said unusual, not awkward. "communicating at two levels" is a participial phrase: the participle doesn't have an explicit subject. However, it is very easy to infer that the subject is the person who asks the question. If your still have concerns about whether the sentence is constructed correctly, I suggest that you write a new question to explain your concerns, Your current question completely misses the point, and asking for a dictionary definition of a word is, anyway , off-topic for this site.

Comment: @JavaLatte I think finally I have understood your viewpoint. That is, "The force of the question is probably ironic, communicating at two levels" = "The force of the question is probably ironic and one who is the speaker communicates at two levels". Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable way of describing it.  It's not written as specifically as that because the speaker is  irrelevant to the meaning of your sentence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150476/discussion-between-gonju-yi-and-javalatte).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit long and complicated, but I think the short answer is "yes". IF someone asks, "Do you have to eat rice pudding every day?", it's POSSIBLE that he means it literally. "Is there some reason why we are forced to eat rice pudding every day?" Perhaps that is all we can afford, or someone has concluded that it is essential for good health, etc. But most likely it is meant ironically. The speaker and the listener both know that nothing is literally forcing us. Rather, he means, "I don't like to eat rice pudding every day. Let's stop."

Sometimes, the answer to such a question is "yes, there is a good reason why we must do this that you are apparently unaware of or don't understand".

Comment: 1. Then, the communicating of Need you...? at level 1 is simply based on the logical meaning(i.e. necessary or obligatory) of the verb need and the communicating of Need you...? at level 2 is based on the ironical element which the speaker has captured from the verb need, so the answer to my second question is yes?

Comment: 2. Secondly, here the word communicate is equivalent to the word convey?

Comment: 3. lastly, the answer to my first question is also yes?